# Laravel Horizon install fail in my local machine

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have install laravel Laravel Framework 6.7.0 in local machine. I have working redis queue and jobs. but i have install horizon using this link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/horizon. but i have not install .
I have atteched sceenshort below Please check.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output `Using version ^4.2 for laravel/horizon` states composer tries to install version 4 of `laravel/horizon` - which is Laravel7 only. You need to install version 3, which is compatible with Laravel6:

```
composer require laravel/horizon ^3.0
```